# Locate the file path on a Joomla website PHP

Tags: joomla2.5

I need to know in which folder is located the address of my joomla site. In the address bar it shows http://www.gybr.com.br/index.php/videos , so where is this page??

Answer (score 1):

The `videos` page would not be located in any particular folder, but is built from a record in the database. You should be able to go to the root of your website hosting files and see the index.php file there, but you won't find any of the pages in the folders, because they don't exist as files. Each are referenced in the database and built accordingly. Joomla then uses a routing class to parse that url and connect it to the appropriate database record.

You would need to log in to the administration side of Joomla and see what menu item type the `videos` page has to determine what component generates the page. This could help you find the correct file if you are trying to change something, but in the end, it will have little relation to the path you are seeing in the url.

Comment: Good explanation! I want to delete the header just above the videos ("Vídeo Relacionado"). I was goint to try to do this in the code, but as you explained it's not like that. Do you have any idea where I should look to delete it?? Please take a look:  http://www.gybr.com.br/index.php?/videos

Comment: Hmm... I don't see it on that page at all, so hopefully you go it already. Otherwise, it is likely either a module title or an article title, so you would want to check either for a "Related Video" module and set it to not display the title or set the article title to not display on the menu item. That is completely a shot in the dark though, so it really could be anything!

Answer (score 0):

To find out the folder, adding the following PHP code to somewhere in your site should do the trick (`index.php` is probably your best bet):

```
<?php
  if (defined('JPATH_BASE')) {
    echo JPATH_BASE;
  }
  else {
    echo getcwd();
  }
?>
```